# VBA For without next error with simple script

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

Below is the simple script I wrote. I don't know why it's giving me the error: for without next. I've searched and the only explanation I could find that could be the reason was that my computer was running too slow for this script, even though I know that can't be the case.

```
For y = 2 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If Month(tbl.DataBodyRange(2, 1)) = Month(tbl.DataBodyRange(2 - 1, 1)) Then
        Next
    Else
        months = months + 1
        Next
    End If
    Exit For
```

Comment: I indented your code properly. Maybe that will help you see your error here.

Comment: thank you, but it's still giving me the for without next error :/

Comment: Of course it is. I didn't change anything but your indentation to help you see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not how you use a for loop. You always start with `For ... To` and end with `Next` at the very end of the loop.

```
For y = 2 To tbl.ListRows.Count
    If Month(tbl.DataBodyRange(2, 1)) = Month(tbl.DataBodyRange(2 - 1, 1)) Then
        'do nothing here
    Else
        months = months + 1
    End If
Next
```

This way it should work. Maybe you intended the `Next` statement to start the next iteration in the loop. But The if-case ensures that nothing else is executed anyway.

Comment: ahh. I thought you had to give it a command after "Then". Thank you!

Comment: If it helped you, feel free to accept this as answer.